# Запрос к серверу через fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

Всем привет. Почему при запросе к серверу получаю такой ответ как на фото.

```
const  sState = fetch(url).then(response => response.json()).then(data => data)
console.log(sState)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему бы нет?

Comment: Потому что fetch возращяет промис

Comment: Then также возращяет промис

Comment: А ответ от сервера лежит в дата это боди кстати

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону async await либо учитесь пользоваться промисами и их результатами

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: Чем отличается? Первый же сниппет в принятом ответе вам подходит

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` - асинхронная операция. Когда ты выводишь сам промис, он находится в состоянии `pending`. Но в тот момент, когда ты разворачиваешь выведенный объект, Хром показывает не снепшот промиса на момент его вывода, а текущее состояние объекта, поэтому (если ответ сервера уже пришёл и обработался) там отображается `fulfilled`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

> А в идеале - попробуйте сначала разобраться с промисами, например, используя [статью по ссылке](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Ispolzovanie_promisov)

```
const process = async (url) => {
  const sState = await fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
  console.log(sState)
};
```